# How can I filter by numbers in an excel sheet using Python codes?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter out the data from my excel sheet using Python.
When I filter by car "Make" and "Model," it works fine, but when I add a "Year," it does not return any data(Empty). It works with me only if I add any text at the beginning of each cell for the "Year" Column. How can I get the program to filter without adding text to every cell in the "Year" column.

[image: here is function code][1]]
[image: Empty results since cells sheet do not start with text]
[image: Return data since cells sheet start with text "A"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`car_year` is user input and [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) are strings in Python. Presumably "Year" is dtype int column, so `df['Year']==car_year` returns a Series of Falses. To get your desired outcome, convert `car_year` to int:

```
car_filter = df[(df['Make']==car_make) & (df['Model']==car_model) & (df['Year']==int(car_year))]
```